# Set output image to current URL link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a bit messy but I'm trying to create a embed function and I'm having trouble setting the IMAGE in the output to the url of the current page the user is on. 
http://jsfiddle.net/KevinOrin/C35WZ/

So in that fiddle `<a id="pinSrc" href="">image</a>` should be `<a id="pinSrc" href="http://jsfiddle.net/KevinOrin/C35WZ/">image</a>`

Thanks

Comment: `alert(document.URL);`

Comment: To add to this, it's recreating the output of the EMBED button on the right side of the pin on Pinterest: http://pinterest.com/pin/263671753156523086/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to the edited fiddle: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/C35WZ/6/)

```
(function ($) {
    var getCode = function (wlink,url) {
        var html;

        html =
            "<div>" +
            "<a href=\""+wlink+"\" target='_blank'>"+
            "<img src=\"" + url + "\" />" +
            "<p>Source <a href=\"www.gossiptalk.info\">GossipTalk</a></p>" +
            "</a>"+
            "</div>";

        return html;
    };


    $(document).on("click", ".embed", function (e) {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        console.log(id);
            url = $("#" + id).attr("src");
var wlink=window.location.href;
        $("#output").val(getCode(wlink,url));
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Let me know whether it works for you.

Comment: That actually removes the link from the image. In the outputted embed code the image needs to be wrapped in a link.

Comment: Yes man, cheers! It ads /show at the end of the URL, is that just from jsfiddle or something needs changing in the code. I didnt see ference to it

Comment: Thanks mate, regarding the \show part i suspect it has to do with jsfiddle, unfortunately I can't put together a webpage to try this out but let me know how it goes ok?

Comment: I put it into my Drupal template, Works great, just need to populate it into a popup instead of textarea. http://gossiptalk.info/pics/villans

Comment: I may even leave it as a textreas once i fix the undefined image src in the output. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help :) Ask a new question if you need help with a popup window.